# Django: Override {{form.as_p}} to add style to each field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-forms

I want to override `{{form.as_p}}` because I need to add styles to every field, but every field has a different style, example:

The first field I need to be like a checklist and the others only text something like that.

My project is in Django 1.11 and Python 3.4.3

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates You can easily make custom form templates

Comment: I'm confused -- if it's just text, then it isn't really a form field, is it?